# how do i change all photos on a page when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

i have a page with a horizontal slide show at the top and under that i have many photos corresponding to the photo which is in the horizontal slideshow above. the pictures on the lower page should be dependant on what image is clicked on in the section above. so when one photo in the top slideshow is clicked it triggers all the below pictures to change. right now i havent been able to figure out how to do this. here is the code i have so far.

this creates the top slideshow.

```
    <?php
if($_GET){
    $galname = $_GET['galname'];
// gallery settings
$itemsPerPagep = '10';         // number of images per page    
$thumb_widthp  = '150';        // width of thumbnails
$thumb_heightp = '220';         // height of thumbnails
$src_folderp   = 'admin/showroom/'.$galname.'';             // current folder
$src_filesp    = scandir($src_folderp); // files in current folder
$extensionsp   = array(".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".gif",".JPG",".JPEG",".PNG",".GIF"); // allowed extensions in photo gallery
```

this code echos the slideshow images one by one

```
if( isset($filesp[$ip]) && is_file( $src_folderp .'/'. $filesp[$ip] ) ) { 
      echo '<a href"#" id="imgsft'.$ip.'" style="cursor:pointer" onClick="">
      <div class="thumb2" style="text-align:center;">
      <span style="padding-bottom:15px;">'.$placep = substr($filesp[$ip], 0 , (strrpos($filesp[$ip], '.'))).'</span>
               <img src="'. $src_folderp .'/'. $filesp[$ip] .'"width="'.$thumb_widthp.'" height="'.$thumb_heightp.'" alt="" style="padding-top:15px;"/>
            </div>  
            </a>';
```

and this code echos the images for the lower parts of the page

```
<?php
include_once("resources/init.php");
include_once("db_conx.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id= '62'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $description = $row["description"];
        $filename = $row["filename"];
        $thumb1 = $row["thumb1"];
        $thumb2 = $row["thumb2"];
        $thumb3 = $row["thumb3"];}
?>
```

on this last part where "id= 62" i need this 'id' variable to be able to change to the correct id number according to the upper slideshow index id#.

how can i get this id variable to be changed to the correct id of the corresponding image when the image is clicked, resulting in all photos on the lower page changing relative to what is stored in the database row

Answer (score 0):

If I am oversimplifying/misunderstanding your problem, please let me know, but you would need to make an AJAX request or reload the page when the image is clicked. You could do this either by making each image a link or adding javascript that is executed when you click on the image. You would then pass the identifier for the image in your request to the backend and use the parameter there.

Comment: javascript shounds like the best solution. how will javascript change the php id variable ?

Comment: you will need to understand AJAX calls such as in jquery and send the query as a parameter to your php script. This parameter will get in the $_GET, $_POST map and you can then insert it into the string to replace the 62 value.

Comment: Whether by AJAX or direct page reloads, you are going to have to learn how to get parameters from a request in php. It is the basis for information exchange between the browser and the backend. Here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: i need to change the id variable without reloading the page

Comment: You will need to learn AJAX in that case and a javascript library in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a link referenced to the div container you want to target, and use jQuery to load/create the section you want?

Also, you can achieve the same effect using the `.collapse` class from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse). I am developing a website that uses it for cases like this.